# How to get Django classifieds running on my local server

Tags: python, django

I am starting on a project for classified ad listing site and found a [template to get me started](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds).

The installation instruction on git are not clear to me.

I created virtual env and installed dependencies using `pip` but I can't finish the installation process: `manage.py runserver` could not be executed and showed `"could not find module sorl.thumbnail"`.

I think there is some error due to folder structure but cannot figure out what. Any ideas?

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB6p3.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the dependency `sorl.thumbnail` is not (successfully) installed.

Try running `pip install sorl-thumbnail==11.05.2`. That should install the module (in the version required by django-classifieds according to the requirements.txt). Check the output for any errors.

Also, make sure that you are using the right environment.

Comment: I have all he dependency installed on my virtualenv , I did in manually but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that you either forgot to install [sorl.thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) or that it is in a separate environment than django-classifieds. To add it manually, download the zip from the specified URL, extract the zip, and, in a command prompt/terminal in the directory you extracted the zip into, and run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`.